# Calculating the "factor difference" of fluorescence values - what phrase to use?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

I have a section in a document that describes a formula used to calculate a "factor difference" (Russian "кратное различие", literally "-fold difference") between two fluorescence values - that is, by how many times one value is higher than the other:

> (section name) Calculation of the Factor Difference between fluorescence values

> Factor difference = mean fluorescence at the highest concentration / mean fluorescence at the lowest concentration

For instance, if the numerator is 10 and the denominator is 2, the "factor difference" would be 10/2 = 5.

I'm not sure that **factor difference** is a naturally-sounding English phrase for this purpose though. What would be a better alternative?

Maybe "fluorescence suppression rate"? But that would deviate further from the Russian original.

Comment: You seem to be describing a “ratio” or “multiplier”.

Comment: I agree, ratio. The -fold seems to be related to five-fold or ten-fold, but there's no word I know for "how many fold". The maximum ratio that a machine could handle could be called "dynamic range", but that would be more for the machine than for samples.